# What's the meaning of "she is a real pip"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-meaning

I heard this expression  in the TV series *Better Call Saul*. A character spoke to a secretary, and  he seemed annoyed.
After he spoke to her chief and said "your secretary is a real pip".
What that could mean? I imagined something negative, but I don't know. 
The dictionary does not report a clear explanation of the meaning referred to a person...

[Pip](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pip)

Comment: Here's [another Oxford definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/pip), but I'm not sure why I got that version as I'm in the UK.

Comment: ...... Which movie?

Comment: Better call Saul, it's a TV series

Comment: Do you know what season and episode and what time in the episode?

Comment: It sounds almost the same as "she's a real brick".

Comment: @ArmthegoodguysinAmerica: S03E02, "Witness", ~19:40.

Answer (score 6):

It's originally American English.

> 3. *colloquial* (originally and chiefly U.S.). Something remarkably good; an excellent or very attractive person or thing.

(*Oxford English Dictionary*)

> *informal* An excellent or very attractive person or thing.

([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/pip))

> *Slang*, *Obsolete*
>   a person or thing much admired

(Webster’s New World College Dictionary, 4th Edition. Copyright © 2010), quoted at [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pip))

In the show, it could have been used sarcastically, like any other positive descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

Jonathon Green, *Chambers Dictionary of Slang* (2008) offers a series of meanings for *pip* as U.S. slang, and conveniently includes approximate dates of first known occurrence for each meaning:

> **pip** *n.* {abbr[eviation of] PIPPIN *n.* ["|mid-17C+| (also **pipkin**, **pippins**) a term of approval or congratulation, applied to a person; thus affectionate term of address *my pippin*"]} **1** |late 19C+| (*orig. US*) the very best, the finest example. **2** |1900s| (US) a negative, bad example. **3** |1920s–30s| (US) an innocent. **4** |1950s| an attractive woman.

The example that the poster asks about clearly uses *pip* in the sense of Green's definition 4.

---

***Early instances of 'pip' used in the relevant sense***

Although Green states that *pip* in the relevant sense originated as US slang, he also says that its lineage goes back to the 1600s (and presumably to Great Britain), as *pippin*.

Green seems to have misgauged the earliest instance of *pip* in the specific sense of "an attractive woman" by several decades. From Rex Beach, [*The Barrier*](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=SCEN19090316.1.4&e=-------en--20--1--txt-txIN-%252522she%252527s+a+pip%252522-------1), serialized in the *Santa Cruz [California] Evening News* (March 16, 1909):

> "Those your kids, too, eh?" Stark continued.
>
> "Yes, and I got another one besides—older, a girl." "**She's a 'pip,'** too," said "No Creek" Lee fervently. "She's plumb beautiful."

From "['Dealin' Out Jobs' Is Organization's Business, Says Ward Heeler in 'The Crack in the Bell'](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83045211/1918-05-13/ed-1/seq-8/#words=%22she%27s%2Ba%2Bpip%22)," in the *Philadelphia [Pennsylvania] Ledger* (May 13, 1918):

> "I very much hope that I may meet you again," he declared with fervor, eyes still clinging to the figure of the girl.
>
> "Oh, I hope so," echoed Sylvy, sincerely enough, though not very confidently.
>
> "Ain't **she a pip**?" demanded Kelly, advancing from the background in which he had temporarily obscured himself.

From "[Loud and Clear: Karl Nakagawa](https://hojishinbun.hoover.org/?a=d&d=tnw19310605-01.1.8&txq=%22she%27s+a+pip%22)," in the *[San Francisco, California] Shin Sekai* (June 5, 1931):

> Like all good boys, he has his weakness. Looks like an interracial romance is in bloom. The writer met his weakness recently and **she's a pip**. One would wonder how such a lovely creature could ever forsake men of her own race. Her form, her pearly white skin, her eyes—what an example of beauty! Makes one's heart go pitter-pat.

And in an episode of the [nationally serialized daily newspaper comic strip *Alley Oop*](https://texashistory.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metapth167502/m1/34/zoom/?q=%22she%27s%20a%20pip%22&resolution=4&lat=5483.5&lon=2266.5) in the *Borger [Texas] Daily Herald* (September 4, 1938) a character named Foozy says this:

> Say—who's th' doll with Oola there? **She's a pip!** My gosh, what gorgeous hair!

Not surprisingly, there are instances from the same period in which speakers use longer forms of *pip* with the same evident meaning. From Stuart Stone, "[Matched by Mail](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn88085187/1910-09-03/ed-1/seq-5/#words=%22she%27s%2Ba%2Bpip%22)," in the *Tacoma [Washington] Times* (September 3, 1910):

> "Oh, Tex—she'll do. **She's a pippinoola**—that Miss Nellie. Take me in and introduce me as her true lovin' heart."

From Joseph Kescel, "[The Mirage](https://texashistory.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metapth198699/m1/6/zoom/?q=%22she%27s%20a%20pip%22&resolution=1.5&lat=5494.628180083213&lon=2483.805922295744)," in the *El Paso Times* (April 6, 1917):

> "Who was that I saw you with a few moments ago?" asked the "Mirage."
>
> "The young lady I wrote to you about, staying over at the Thompsons'. She's the best that has come this way in a long time. Sure, you're going to meet her. You'll have to speak loudly to her—hearing's not very good. Too bad too for **she's a pippin**."

It bears noting in connection with *pippin* that the word has been applied to "a crisp tart apple having usu. yellow or greenish-yellow skin strongly flushed with red and used esp. for cooking" since the fifteenth century, according to *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003). The *Eleventh Collegiate* considers the later meaning of *pippin*—"a highly admired or or very admirable person or thing"—to have emerged from the original apple meaning.

Answer (score -1):

Both these choices are correct. PIP references the Dickens character Philip Pirrup from “Great Expections” who underestimates others, overestimates himself, gets up to a lot of trouble but is still well liked by most. SPOT ON! I am in my seventies and remember my father’s folks (from Yorkshire, England) using this expression and sometimes at me. Our daughter who loving sometimes refers to her DUB (Dublin, Ireland) husband Philip Price as Pip! QED

Comment: Please add a citation with the meanings you specify.

Comment: The chances of a Dickens reference appearing in "Call Saul" (an American series about a roguish but likeable lawyer in modern day America) are so exceedingly small that you would have to go some distance to show that connection.

Answer (score -2):

Could it be from Dickens' "Great Expectations"?  The character, Pip (short for Philip Pirrip), demonstrates the qualities which would make someone "a pip".

He underestimates others, overestimates himself, gets up to a lot of trouble but is still well liked by most.

Comment: This answer will need something more than a guess to be taken seriously.. Can you back it up in some way?