# What's an alternative meaning of being "a pip"?

Tags: meaning

The system wouldn't let me comment, so....  The first time I heard the expression "pip" applied to an individual was in the 1970s television show *All in the Family*.  Archie Bunker would say to his wife throughout the series: "Edith, you're a real pip," in a sarcastic manner whenever she made a comment that he considered not very intelligent.  He meant it as the opposite of "excellent," more along the lines of how it was used in *Better Call Saul*.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: One of the meanings of [pip](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pip) at Merriam-Webster is "one extraordinary of its kind". [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pip) has the same meaning tagged as "(US, colloquial) Something or someone excellent, of high quality." It's obvious that Archie was using that sarcastically. What other information do you require that's not in the dictionary?

Comment: I guess this is a duplicate of [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/408232/whats-the-meaning-of-she-is-a-real-pip) which the OP references. But this is your chance to explain what else you want to know. Or is this just a comment without a question?

Comment: @StuartF She did start out by saying she posted this as a question because she doesn't have enough rep to comment. So I guess the answer is "yes".